# Passing pointers to function without copying it

Tags: c++, pointers, stl

How do I pass data around my program without copying it every time?

Specifically, when calling `sim(ohlc)` I want to just pass the pointer reference, I don't want to copy the data to the function.

This is the program I made, but I'm not sure this is the best way to do it (specially when it comes to speed and memory usage).

I think I'm not passing the pointer to `sim(ohlc)` like I should, but if I try `sim(&ohlc)` I don't know how to change the `sim` function to accept that.

```
   struct ohlcS {
        vector<unsigned int> timestamp;
        vector<float> open;
        vector<float> high;
        vector<float> low;
        vector<float> close;
        vector<float> volume;
    } ;


ohlcS *read_csv(string file_name) {
    // open file and read stuff
    if (read_error)
        return NULL;
    static ohlcS ohlc;
    ohlc.timestamp.push_back(read_value);
    return &ohlc;
}

int sim(ohlcS* ohlc) {
    // do stuff
    return 1;
}


main() {
    ohlcS *ohlc = read_csv(input_file);
    results = sim(ohlc);
}
```

Comment: You passing to the `sim()`-function exactly a pointer.

Comment: When you pass the pointer to `sim()`, you don't copy the data. Just the pointer.

Comment: Just a suggestion, do not use class name as variable name ohlc *ohlc is very confusing.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy So, this is the correct way to do it?

Comment: @EricFortin Ok, I'll change that.

Comment: @jbssm yes although returning the address of a function's static variable is questionable.

Comment: @jbssm If your problem was only to pass pointer to a function(which means also to disallow copying data) - sure.

Comment: You already pass a pointer to sim because the object ohlc is of type ohlc*. Your code would be a lot more readable if you picked variable names that are different from type names.

Comment: As your code is, there is no data copy, only a copy of a pointer value (which is somenthing like sizeof(int)).

Comment: @EricFortin If I don't put it static the compiler gives me a warning, that's why I did it. In any case I don't want to change the values of olhc after I read them from the file. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @jbssm I would either allocate on the heap(and return pointer) or send it to this function(from the caller) by reference.

Comment: Returning a non-`const` pointer to a `static` local may be legal, but is rarely a good idea.  Try returning a `unique_ptr`

Comment: @Yakk and in what part do I need to do that?

Comment: Read csv should return a `std::unique_ptr<ohlcS>`.  It gets created via `new ohkcS` within tue function.  The lifetime of the data is then controlled, and not the data is not (opaquely) shared.  `move` is used to pass its ownership around, and `,get()` is used to pass it to other functions.

Answer (score 2):

It's C++, use a reference. It's safe, since you return a static object.

```
static ohlc ohlc_not_found;

ohlc &read_csv(string file_name) {
    // open file and read stuff
    if(error_while_opening)
    {
        return ohlc_not_found;
    }
    static ohlc loc_ohlc;
    loc_ohlc.timestamp.push_back(read_value);
    return loc_ohlc;
}

int sim(const ohlc& par_ohlc) {
    // do stuff
    return 1;
}

....
 ohlc& var_ohlc = read_csv(input_file);
 if(var_ohlc == ohlc_not_found)
 {
      // error handling
      return;
 }
 results = sim(var_ohlc);
```

If you want to modify `par_ohlc` in sim, do not make it const.

and it's not recommended to use `ohlc` for both class and variable name :(

Comment: But how can I return a NULL from read_csv this way? In case I can't read the file?

Comment: You can pass in an extra parameter (such as `int& error_indicator`) to tell the user if there was an error or not. The problem with pointers is that the human brain automatically tries to free them :) Or you can declare a global static empty ohlc (`ohlc_not_found`) variable, and set the return value to that in case of error.

Comment: You can throw a `std::invalid_argument` exception.

Comment: This doesn't work, it says:  `error: invalid operands to binary expression ('ohlc' and 'ohlc')` I think it's because the ohlc doesn't have the == implemented?

Comment: @walle IO exception is not an invalid argument, a specific IO exception would be better here.

Comment: @Paranaix For me thats ok, because it refers to the 'string file_name' argument.

Answer (score 1):

In line:

```
results = sim(ohlc);
```

you are passing `ohlc` pointer to sim function, no deep data copy is done, only 32bit pointer value is copied.

Answer (score 1):

This pushes the address (32 bit value) onto the stack.

```
results = sim(ohlc);
```

Like:

```
  ; ...
  push eax ; addr of struct/class/whatever
  call function ; jump to function

  ; ...

function:
  push ebp
  mov ebp, esp
  mov eax, [ebp+8] ; ebp+8 is the 32 bit value you pushed before onto the stack
                   ; -> your pointer
```

Take a look [at this](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/labmanual/c-prog-mixing.html) and maybe [that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) too.

Version 2

```
  ; ...
  push eax ; addr of struct/class/whatever
  jmp function ; jump to function
autolbl001:

  ; ...

function:
  push ebp
  mov ebp, esp
  mov eax, [ebp+8] ; ebp+8 is the 32 bit value you pushed before onto the stack
  ; ...
  jmp autolbl001
```

Comment: Its not a jump but a call, CALL does alot more than JMP (like pushing the return address). Also notice that a compiler could theoretically implement refererences (not pointers) without pushing anything. Moreover the calling convention and optimization is very important too (e.g fastcall).

Comment: You're right, it's a `call`, good call ;). My answer was not intendet to go into every detail of how a CPU works and whatsoever any compiler does or doesn't do. I just wanted to push it to the low level direction for better basic understanding.

Comment: @Paranaix and there also could be an autogenerated label by your compiler that does what my edited code does.